# how to log-in and execute ftp commands in native windows telnet client program using only one command

Tags: windows, ftp, ftp-client

What I want to do is issuing one command that contains ftp commands that I want to execute. I want my command to contatin username, password and commands.

I only can use windows native ftp client program, and it seems it does not provide any help regarding this. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you read 'ftp /?' for example

```
Ftp -s:YouFileWithFtpCommands
```